# Django Admin list_display: Link to filtered model

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-admin

I want to make a music library app and in the admin/artist page I would like to link to a list with all the albums by the artist.

Models look like this:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    artistName = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank = False) 
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank = False) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.artistName

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    albumName = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank = False)
    year = models.IntegerField(blank = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.albumName
```

Now for the admin part, I imagine that I make an ArtistAdmin model and then somehow use list_display to link to a filtered version of the Album model. Can anyone tell me how to do this or suggest a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm having exactly the same need; here's the simplest way I came up so far.

Admin lists have [list_filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter), with which you can, for example, do that (assuming you register the admin classes and so on):

```
class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('artist', 'albumName', 'year',)
list_filter = ('artist',)
```

This will add a right column in your admin site with the list of artists, and if you click on one, the Albums list will be filtered to show only those which are made by this artist.

Having that, and here's the trick, turns out that even if you don't declare "list_filter", Django will still filter things according to the URL parameters.
So, I activated the filters, I clicked in one of my "artists", so the list got filtered and I could see how it formats the URL, which is something like
[…]/admin/app_name/model_name/?foreignKeyName__id__exact=XX

In your case I imagine it will look similar to:
[…]/admin/music_library/album/?artist__id__exact=XX

Try to follow these steps, then remove the line "list_filter", and you will see that the URL still works.

So now we know that the only thing we need is to pass the param artist__id__exact=XX, so we have to append a column with a button for that.

```
class ArtistAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('artistName', 'genre', 'artists_list_field')

def artists_list_field(self, obj):
    base_url = reverse('admin:music_library_album_changelist')
    return mark_safe(u'<a href="%s?artist_id__exact=%d">Albums</a>' % (
        base_url, obj.id))
```

With this you have it working.
I hope it's useful!

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a lot:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use list_display and list_filter in admin.py like this:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 

    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name',)
    list_filter = ('company__name', 'first_name',) # company is a model which has relation to the Person model
```

Then in your admin.py you should add PersonAdmin to your model :

```
admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

---

[Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Your suggestion doesn't solve my problem. I want to go to the ArtistAdmin page and then be able to click a link that takes me to the AlbumAdmin page which is filtered by the artist name. Any suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: Your answer is not answering the question.